# Cabal fails updating of cabal-install

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

Every time I install a library, cabal tells me to install a new version of cabal-install. Despite the fact that i run (with apparent success) the procedure that list below, the version of cabal-install remains unchanged. Where I am going wrong? (My OS is Window 7 64-bits)

My User PATH is C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin

System variables: CABAL_DIR = C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal

BEFORE the update

```
C:\Users\Alberto>cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

C:\Users\Alberto>cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

C:\Users\Alberto>cabal install cabal-install
```

AFTER the update

```
Linking dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe ...
Installing executable(s) in C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
Installed cabal-install-1.18.0.2

C:\Users\Alberto>cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

But:

```
C:\Users\Alberto>C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cabal.exe -V
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1.2 of the Cabal library
```

I am very confused about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the output of `C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cabal.exe -V`?

Comment: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cabal.exe -V 
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1.2 of the Cabal library

Comment: OK, that just means that the cabal.exe file selected by default is not the right one, that's all. Check `echo %PATH%` (I know, you said there is just one directory there, but, unless you checked with `echo`, the real PATH variable could be different). Also check if you have `cabal.exe` file in your current directory.

Comment: Solved it for me too. Hat two paths:
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin
 and the AppData\Roaming... path.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to set your PATH to make sure that `C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin` is at/near the beginning.

You can set this in "Control Panel" -> "System" -> "Advanced System Settings" -> "Advanced" -> "Environment Variables" and then edit the "User variables".

Comment: I've edited my question with the path, that is C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin

Answer (score 1):

What is your `$PATH`? It seems that you are using a `cabal` binary from somewhere else than `C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin`, so that one continues to be used when you type `cabal`.

Comment: I've edited my question with the path, that is C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin